# Can the Curie temperature be higher than the Curie-Weiss parameter?

Tags: magnetic-fields, temperature

I did a Curie-Weiss fit to my ferromagnetic data and found a Curie-Weiss parameter $\Theta_{CW}$ lower than the Curie temperature $T_C$. My question is, I would expect that the Curie-Weiss parameter is larger because it gives us information about the molecular field, in which case it is always larger than the Curie Temperature.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should include more information about what you are trying to do. Link to which equation you are trying to fit with what approximation, so we can read the context. It is not clear to us how things are defined in your problem. If you have pictures of your fitting it would be great to include.